# Updating information in Custom fields within a tab not saving since update to 4.7.0

Tags: custom-fields, upgrade, database, error, fields

Civicrm 4.7.0
Joomla 3.4.8

When editing or adding information contained within a custom field within a tab, after hitting save, the information does not remain.

Also receive the following error when trying to view information contained wihtin a tab within a table:

Datatables warning: table id=records -Ajax error
For more information please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you require more info.

Thanks

Comment: I was going to say 'have you confirmed on demo/sandbox' but looks like the Joomla versions do not get built automatically. not sure who to shoulder tap about getting that sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I did manage to test the same against 4.7.0 and we do have an issue. so, please raise an issue for the same

Also I did manage to test the same against Civicrm Version 4.6.11 and everything works perfectly. so at this time I would recommend you to install civicrm Version 4.6.11 for time being and wait for the next version and see if that gets fixed

Comment: I actually had reverted back to 4.6.11, but then I get some error when loading civicrm... I didn't make note of the error, just reupdated to 4.7.0.. I'll revert back and get the error and post it later today.,

Thanks.

Comment: sure. please try to post a detailed error message - that will be easy to answer - thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I was able to install 4.6.11 right away. The installation appeared to complete successfully, but when trying to access the civicrm dashboard via the joomla back end, I get the following page:

http://imgur.com/miDK8xY

Comment: For completeness, here's the issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17949

Comment: @trvrtwr the error is to do with missing column in table civicrm_domain. So, I should test - but for now you can create an column "config_backend" with datatype "text" in the Civicrm DB manually which will fix the issue

Comment: @Ramesh I've created the column in the civicrm_domain table as suggested. Civicrm is now returning the error: Fatal DB error, exiting, seems like your schema does not have civicrm_setting table.

When I check the database, the civicrm_setting table does indeed exist.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: @Remsh Just wondering if you have any more insight into my issue. I appreciate your help so far.

Thanks

Comment: @trvrtwr sorry was bit away - do you still have the issue

Comment: @ramesh I was able to correct the updating of the custom fields issue using the fix here: https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/civicrm-core/commit/5024760cb7e50846f638330cd95974b22dfd6cee

But I'm still unable to upload files to any custom fields, and I'm also receiving an ajax error when trying to view the relationships tab, which I posted about here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/ajax-error-when-trying-to-view-relationships-tab/9524#9524

All of your help has been greatly appreciated!

Comment: One quick Question did you manage to switch to CiviCRM previous version 4.6.11

Comment: I actually did not. I gave up on that after I received the error: Fatal DB error, exiting, seems like your schema does not have civicrm_setting table.

Note - I checked and the civicrm_setting table does indeed exist.

Comment: ok then let me create an test site in my local and will let you know

Comment: @Ramesh Thank you for all the time you have put into this. I don't know if I should start a new thread, but another issue I have found with 4.7.1 is when importing individuals. If there's custom fields in the import, the import returns the error: "Invalid value for custom field'' on every line. 

Importing worked fine pre- 4.7.1 for me.

As always, your help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to create an Issue for both the issues as it is an bug in version 4.7.1

Comment: @Rameh, Hi just wondering if you were able to replicate my issue with reverting back to 4.6.11?

Thanks!